# Is there an embedded in-process Google Spanner implementation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

My organisation is working on the app that is being deployed to GCP and as the system of record was chosen to use Google Spanner.

Is there a way to test my DAOs without actually connecting to the GCP and running queries against a live instance?

It is very inconvenient to perform testing of Spanner DAO by launching integration tests using DEV instance.

I would like to be able to launch an in-process Google Spanner.

Comment: It's called an emulator. As the time of writting, there is no emulator for Spanner.